# Alternative for ViewData and QueryString

Tags: model-view-controller, c#-3.0

I have a page(a.aspx) to which im navigating from two different pages(ie there is a link in these two pages where it navigates to a.aspx)

to differentiate from which page i was navigated to a.aspx i used the below code.

passed Querystrings(B1,B2) to the target page as below

```
Html.ActionLink("test" "Testing", new { Controller = "Stats",prev="B1"},new { @class = "link",target="_self" })
Html.ActionLink("test" "Testing", new { Controller = "Stats",prev="B2"},new { @class = "link",target="_self" })
```

and in the action of the target page controller i used the below code

```
ViewData["prev"] = Request.QueryString["prev"].ToString();
```

and im using this ViewData in the target page ie a.aspx.This is working fine..
Im abit reluctant to use Query.string and ViewData for the above requirement.Please suggest any other alternative approach for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

Get the name of the controller

```
 @ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue
```

Get the name of the action

```
@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue
```

I found that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018083/how-can-i-find-out-the-name-of-the-controller-action-that-called-my-view-in-mvc3).

Answer (score 0):

Why not navigate to two separate actions that return the same view?  Then, return a model to the view that will indicate the "from" page.  You'll know which page you came from by virtue of which action gets hit.  It's cleaner, far less complicated, and easier to maintain than trying to pass around this sort of thing in a querystring, viewdata, viewbag, etc.  That being said, if you are having to do a lot of this sort of thing, creating separate actions each time around is not reali